colorpicker and field validation
I am using TabularInlines to gather some information, one of which is a colorfield:
class UnitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ["date", "name", "label", "color"]
        widgets = {"color": TextInput(attrs={'type': 'color'}),}

class UnitTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = UnitForm
    model = Unit
    extra = 0 ##workaround


class StockAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = []
    inlines = [UnitTabularInline]

My problem is, without the extra = 0 switch, I always see 3 "empty" fields (which I actually want to see). But I cannot save my form, if I do not fill out all the fields, because the colorpicker has a preselected value. It seems that when input has type="color" there is always a color defined, and there's no way to set that string to empty.
Can I somehow skip form validation for fields, that only have color in self.chagned_data or something like this? I would like the other edits to be saved.
The model:
class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label = models.CharField("extra label", max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True, blank=True)

